# 3D visualization of some data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, surface

This is my data matrix in MATLAB:

```
a = [43.676289  -79.477386  1
     43.676370  -79.477107  5
     43.676517  -79.477375  20
     43.676417  -79.477509  8
     43.676129  -79.477278  15];
```

The first column is `Y` axis, the second column is `X` axis and the third column is my data. How can I draw a bar graph, and adjust the color of the bars according to the value of data (like `colorbar` in a surface plot) for each data point in MATLAB?

I added an example graph which I drew for another data matrix. In this example X, Y, and Z were linear and I could draw this graph using 'surf' command with no problem. I need to draw the same graph for mentioned data, but the unit of the `XY` axis is not compatible with `Z`, and this confused me.

[image: Example graph]

Just as an additional comment, if we plot only the XY plane, the result looks like the next picture:

```
scatter(a(:,2),a(:,1),'*')
```

[image: XY PLANE ONLY]

Moreover, this is a simple example that might be useful to expand it:

```
z = [5     0     2     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:1:3);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the code/data from the plot which worked.

Comment: Sorry @Wolfie i didn't know how to reply here so I edited the question by adding more information. About the code which worked, that is a simple 'meshgrid' command and 'surf' plot as you can see. Thanks

Comment: Editing the question is the correct way to add more information. Keep code formatting simple and just use indentations - you cannot run MATLAB code snippets in the browser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can do - build `Z` as a matrix from your data:

```
a = [43.676289   -79.477386  1
     43.676370   -79.477107  5
     43.676517   -79.477375  20
     43.676417   -79.477509  8
     43.676129   -79.477278  15];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(sort(a(:,2)),sort(a(:,1)));
Z = zeros(size(X));
for k = 1:size(a,1)
    xind = abs(X-a(k,2))<eps;
    yind = abs(Y-a(k,1))<eps;
    Z(xind & yind) = a(k,3);
end
```

Typing `surf(X,Y,Z)` will give you this:

[image]

However, I think that `bar3` might be a better choice:

```
b = bar3(sort(a(:,1)),Z);
xticklabels(sort(a(:,2)));
cdata_sz = size(b(1).CData);
z_color = repelem(Z,6,4);
z_color(abs(z_color)<1) = nan;
z_color = mat2cell(z_color,...
    cdata_sz(1),ones(1,size(Z,2))*cdata_sz(2));
set(b,{'CData'},z_color.')
view(-70,30)
```

[image: bar3]

Comment: This is great! Thanks @EBH ! Just as an additional option, do you have any idea how to connect these points together to make a surface? Assume I measure height of a mountain in a few points and I want to draw model of the mountain by having those few sample points. I hope I explained well. Anyways thanks for the first answer.

Comment: @user8296976 you welcome! If l get your intention right, than this is exactly what `surf`does. Why isn't it good for you?

Comment: The problem with Surf is the fact that it goes to zero when there is no data available. But i want to have a smooth surface between available points. The more sample point I have, the more accurate model I can creat ....

Comment: So it's not about visualization, it's about interpolation. Take a look on `interp` and `interp2` as a start. Also look for methods of spline. Anyway, that's a subject for a totally different question.

Comment: That was a good start point for next step. At this time I just needed that 'bar3' graph.

Comment: do you have any idea how to use color codes to visualize my data? I mean instead of drawing bars how can I use like red for highest valie and yellow for lowest value. Thanks

Comment: Try [`imagesc(Z)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html?s_tid=doc_ta), and if this doesn't help ask a new question, to explain what you want in more details. Also, notice that I have edited the answer, so now you can use any matrix `C` in the size of `Z` to set the colors, even if you don't want them to be by height (just change to `z_color = repelem(C,6,4);` with your `C`).

Comment: @user8296976 You may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423394/how-to-set-a-color-by-height-for-a-3d-bar-plot) for a generalization and more details about this answer

Comment: Thank you EBH for your time. That was a great answer